# How to define a MS Access global variable using a sql string

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

First, I have searched for an answer to this question but all searches have found answers to how to use a global variable in a query.  I know how to do that.

What I want to do is create a query object which will call UseRates that are being calculated as data is changed - this is simple.  The unknown answer is how to call this query (or input the results of this query) into a global variable such that the global variable definition would look something like (name of the query object is qryUseRates):

```
Public gUseRate1 = "SELECT qryUseRates.UseRate FROM qryUseRates WHERE lngAgeGrp = 1"
```

Then, of course define 4 more global variables similarly for the other 4 use rates (changing the where clause for each).

The reason: the use rates are calculated with all geographical areas aggregated but then they are applied to each geographical area separately.  Thus, qryUseRates returns 5 rows but the query that uses these rates have close to 100 rows such that I don't see a way to join the 2 queries.

Just a follow up; Once the variable is defined I would do:

```
Public Function GetUseRate1()
getuserate1 = gUseRate1
```

Then go to a new query object and wherever I need it, I would use GetUseRate1().  When a global variable is properly defined, this seems to work - tried it just using something simple to define the global variable.

Comment: So your question is *How do I run a query and read the resulting field into a variable?*? (Actually, you probably should read into an array, so you can keep all variables together, but you *can* use five separate variables.) If that's *not* what you're asking, then I'm afraid I can't make sense of what you wrote.

Comment: Ken, That is what I am looking for.  Thanks, I see that Gustav has it with DLookup().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DLookup:

```
Public gUseRate1 As Currency
gUseRate1 = DLookup("UseRate", "qryUseRates", "lngAgeGrp = 1")
```

If "not found" may be expected:

```
gUseRate1 = Nz(DLookup("UseRate", "qryUseRates", "lngAgeGrp = 1"), 0)
```

Comment: Exactly!  Thanks a bunch.  I started down the path of DLookup() but then turned to Global Variables before I got the answer I needed since Global was needed for another use.  I like them both and now have them in my arsenal.  Thanks again.